# TinyMCE Autoresize

Tags: wp-admin, tinymce, editor, post-editor, plugin-tinymce

Looking for a way to make the TinyMCE editor always relative to it's content so that the height of the editor changes accordingly to how much text/images it contains.

There seem to be plugins for TinyMCE for this already, but I'm not sure on how to apply it for the Wordpress version: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:autoresize

```
function init_tinymce_autoresize($initArray){
   $initArray['plugins'] = "autoresize";
   return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'init_tinymce_autoresize');
```

Does not work.

Ideas?

Comment: Not that it helps answer your question, but you could be clobbering other plugins with that code.  In my case, $initArray['plugins'] is already populated when the tiny_mce_before_init filter is called.  You may be safer appending ",autoresize" (it seems to be a comma-delimited string) if it's not empty.

Comment: I had a problem with the editor resizing on every keypress (including cursors).  I didn't solve it, but kept a little sanity by adding `$initArray['autoresize_max_height'] = '500';` to the `init_tinymce_autoresize` function above (in case it helps someone else).

Comment: @Hobo I know I would overwrite other plugins by doing as I initially wrote in the question, that was just for debugging purposes. As autoresize isn't part of TinyMCE for Wordpress it wouldn't work however I tried it. The plugin I wrote below does however work.

Comment: fair enough.  I'm just grateful for your solution (and timing - I can't believe you only asked this two days ago).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution. There's a slight problem as it does not recognize when images are added to the editor.

1: Create a folder with the name tinymce-autoresize in the plugins folder.
2. Create a file in tinymce-autoresize named `tinymce_autoresize.php` with this content:

```
function intialize_autoresize_plugin() {
    // Check user permission
    if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
        return;

    // Add only in Rich Editor mode
    if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
        add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "autoresize_plugin_load");
    }
}

function autoresize_plugin_load($plugin_array) {
    $plug = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/tinymce-autoresize/editor_plugin.js'; 
    $plugin_array['autoresize'] = $plug;
    return $plugin_array;
    }

add_action('init', 'intialize_autoresize_plugin');
```

3. Create a file in tinymce-autoresize named `editor_plugin.js` with this content:

```
/**
 * editor_plugin_src.js
 *
 * Copyright 2009, Moxiecode Systems AB
 * Released under LGPL License.
 *
 * License: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/license
 * Contributing: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/contributing
 */

(function() {
    /**
     * Auto Resize
     *
     * This plugin automatically resizes the content area to fit its content height.
     * It will retain a minimum height, which is the height of the content area when
     * it's initialized.
     */
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.AutoResizePlugin', {
        /**
         * Initializes the plugin, this will be executed after the plugin has been created.
         * This call is done before the editor instance has finished it's initialization so use the onInit event
         * of the editor instance to intercept that event.
         *
         * @param {tinymce.Editor} ed Editor instance that the plugin is initialized in.
         * @param {string} url Absolute URL to where the plugin is located.
         */
        init : function(ed, url) {
            var t = this, oldSize = 0;

            if (ed.getParam('fullscreen_is_enabled'))
                return;

            /**
             * This method gets executed each time the editor needs to resize.
             */
            function resize() {
                var deltaSize, d = ed.getDoc(), body = d.body, de = d.documentElement, DOM = tinymce.DOM, resizeHeight = t.autoresize_min_height, myHeight;

                // Get height differently depending on the browser used
                myHeight = tinymce.isIE ? body.scrollHeight : (tinymce.isWebKit && body.clientHeight == 0 ? 0 : body.offsetHeight);

                // Don't make it smaller than the minimum height
                if (myHeight > t.autoresize_min_height)
                    resizeHeight = myHeight;

                // If a maximum height has been defined don't exceed this height
                if (t.autoresize_max_height && myHeight > t.autoresize_max_height) {
                    resizeHeight = t.autoresize_max_height;
                    body.style.overflowY = "auto";
                    de.style.overflowY = "auto"; // Old IE
                } else {
                    body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
                    de.style.overflowY = "hidden"; // Old IE
                    body.scrollTop = 0;
                }

                // Resize content element
                if (resizeHeight !== oldSize) {
                    deltaSize = resizeHeight - oldSize;
                    DOM.setStyle(DOM.get(ed.id + '_ifr'), 'height', resizeHeight + 'px');
                    oldSize = resizeHeight;

                    // WebKit doesn't decrease the size of the body element until the iframe gets resized
                    // So we need to continue to resize the iframe down until the size gets fixed
                    if (tinymce.isWebKit && deltaSize < 0)
                        resize();
                }
            };

            t.editor = ed;

            // Define minimum height
            t.autoresize_min_height = parseInt(ed.getParam('autoresize_min_height', ed.getElement().offsetHeight));

            // Define maximum height
            t.autoresize_max_height = parseInt(ed.getParam('autoresize_max_height', 0));

            // Add padding at the bottom for better UX
            ed.onInit.add(function(ed){
                ed.dom.setStyle(ed.getBody(), 'paddingBottom', ed.getParam('autoresize_bottom_margin', 25) + 'px');
            });

            // Add appropriate listeners for resizing content area
            ed.onChange.add(resize);
            ed.onSetContent.add(resize);
            ed.onPaste.add(resize);
            ed.onKeyUp.add(resize);
            ed.onPostRender.add(resize);

            if (ed.getParam('autoresize_on_init', true)) {
            //  ed.onLoad.add(resize);
                ed.onLoadContent.add(resize);
            }

            // Register the command so that it can be invoked by using tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceExample');
            ed.addCommand('mceAutoResize', resize);
        },

        /**
         * Returns information about the plugin as a name/value array.
         * The current keys are longname, author, authorurl, infourl and version.
         *
         * @return {Object} Name/value array containing information about the plugin.
         */
        getInfo : function() {
            return {
                longname : 'Auto Resize',
                author : 'Moxiecode Systems AB',
                authorurl : 'http://tinymce.moxiecode.com',
                infourl : 'http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/autoresize',
                version : tinymce.majorVersion + "." + tinymce.minorVersion
            };
        }
    });

    // Register plugin
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('autoresize', tinymce.plugins.AutoResizePlugin);
})();
```

Activate it and you're done!

Comment: I didi exactly that, inside wp-content/plugins/, then activated the plugins with no error but the TinyMCE textareas don't expand when writing.

Answer (score 0):

The Autoresize plugin is already built into WordPress with the name "`wpautoresize`".

The wpautoresize plugin adds the following TinyMCE editor commands:

1. `editor.execCommand('wpAutoResizeOn')` .. enable autoresize
2. `editor.execCommand('wpAutoResizeOff')` .. disable autoresize
3. `editor.execCommand('wpAutoResize')` .. resize the editor to fit the contents (e.g., after programmatically changing the content)

### How to use it

Generate the tinyMCE editor using [`wp_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/). This function will generate the full tinyMCE editor (with the "Add Media" and "Visual/Text" buttons at the top). This function also loads the "wpautoresize" plugin for you.

You only need to activate the autoresize-mode once the page loaded. This JS code will do this for you: `editor.execCommand("wpAutoResizeOn")`.

**Full code sample**

Here is a sample PHP hook which generates a TinyMCE editor and also adds the JS code to instantly enable the autoresize-mode on initialization:

```php
<?php
// Generate the WordPress-TinyMCE editor:
wp_editor('', 'my_editor');

// Output the JS code which enabled the autoresize-plugin on page load:
?>
<script>
tinymce.on('AddEditor', function (inst) {
    inst.editor.on('init', function () {
        inst.editor.execCommand('wpAutoResizeOn');
    });
});
</script>
<?php
```

---

### Special Case: Autoresize in "teeny" mode

The "[teeny](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/_WP_Editors/parse_settings/)" mode does not load the wpautoresize plugin, so you need to manually enqueue the TinyMCE plugin before when calling `wp_editor()`.

You can do this by using the filter [`teeny_mce_plugins`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/teeny_mce_plugins/) - the filter value is an array of all plugins to load. Simply add the plugin "wpautoresize" to that list.

**Full code sample**

```php
<?php
// Add this filter BEFORE calling wp_editor():
add_filter( 'teeny_mce_plugins', 'my_add_autoresize_pugin' );

// Generate the Teeny-TinyMCE editor:
wp_editor('', 'my_teeny_editor', [ 'teeny' => true ]);

// Output the JS code which enabled the autoresize-plugin on page load:
?>
<script>
tinymce.on('AddEditor', function (inst) {
    inst.editor.on('init', function () {
        inst.editor.execCommand('wpAutoResizeOn');
    });
});
</script>

// ...

// This filter handler enqueues the wpautoresize plugin in teeny mode:
function my_add_autoresize_pugin( $plugins ) {
    $plugins[] = 'wpautoresize';
    return $plugins;
}
```